# "Wordpress" should be in Pascal Case, as "WordPress", in the blog's footer

Tags: bug, status-completed, blog, the-overflow

In [*The Overflow*](https://stackoverflow.blog/) blog's footer the word *"Wordpress"* should be stylized in Pascal Case as *"WordPress"*. That's how it's usually written, see [wordpress.com](https://wordpress.com).

[image: screenshot of blog footer]

Comment: Title case? It spelled *"[WordPress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordPress)"* and is independent of casing. "Wordpress" is a ***very*** common misspelling of "WordPress".

Comment: Ahem, Pascal Case (aka Upper Camel Case), ahem

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q I'm a bit confused right now of exactly what to call it...

Comment: I urge the previous editor (not Sonic) to read the article they linked *very* closely - the title case is for Capitalized Words, the correct case for WordPress is PascalCase.

Comment: @bad_coder it's WordPressCase. ;-)

Comment: I want to split the difference and just go "The appropriate case" :D

Comment: I love that this post title doesn't even have WordPress in Pascal case, even though it's complaining about WordPress not being in Pascal case in the footer.  That irony is delicious.

Comment: I think that is intentional, @GeorgeStocker. I even left it be when editing to preserve the play despite considering correcting it.

Comment: I've edited to use the correct case for WordPress in the title. While there are arguments for and against doing so, IMO, it's better to show a correct version in the title, as that is more likely to reinforce correct usage. Most people only ever see the title of a post and never click to open the full question. For something like this, having only the incorrect version in the title provides yet another place where people see the incorrect usage, which reinforces using it in the incorrect way.

Comment: @Makyen I agree that showing correct examples of stylizing is the best way to lead users to mimic the right way of writing it. Good edit!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been fixed, it's currently displayed as shown in the screenshot:

[image: screenshot of WordPress in blog's footer]